# Datewise count and date range count using Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, select

I have a data as shown in the table (image).  I want to find the no. of New and Review patients (head count) on a day and for a range of date.

Table data is (as in attached image)

| RegNo | VisitID | VisitDate | NewReview | DocID | Specialisation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 301573 | RE410429 | 10-07-2021 | Review | DOC00082 | SCOM0002 |
| 259717 | RE410452 | 10-07-2021 | Review | DOC00082 | SCOM0002 |
| 305781 | RE410474 | 10-07-2021 | New | DOC00001 | SCOM0002 |
| 301573 | RE410536 | 10-07-2021 | Review | DOC00007 | SCOM0025 |
| 305287 | RE410544 | 10-07-2021 | Review | DOC00004 | SCOM0003 |
| 305781 | RE410570 | 10-07-2021 | Review | DOC00004 | SCOM0003 |
| 197248 | RE410573 | 10-07-2021 | Review | DOC00179 | SCOM0003 |
| 291838 | RE410574 | 10-07-2021 | Review | DOC00179 | SCOM0003 |
| 305464 | RE410579 | 10-07-2021 | Review | DOC00152 | SCOM0018 |
| 305787 | RE410609 | 12-07-2021 | New | DOC00082 | SCOM0002 |
| 305801 | RE410643 | 12-07-2021 | New | DOC00082 | SCOM0002 |
| 305626 | RE410663 | 12-07-2021 | Review | DOC00082 | SCOM0002 |
| 305287 | RE410697 | 12-07-2021 | Review | DOC00004 | SCOM0003 |
| 305802 | RE410711 | 12-07-2021 | Review | DOC00004 | SCOM0003 |
| 305464 | RE410714 | 12-07-2021 | Review | DOC00004 | SCOM0003 |
| 197248 | RE410721 | 12-07-2021 | Review | DOC00179 | SCOM0003 |
| 243161 | RE410723 | 12-07-2021 | Review | DOC00015 | SCOM0014 |
| 291838 | RE410724 | 12-07-2021 | Review | DOC00179 | SCOM0003 |

When I take a report for each date, I want the output to be

| Date | New | Review |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10-07-2021 | 1 | 6 |
| 12-07-2021 | 2 | 7 |

(The RegNo 305781 is considered only under 'New' (on 10th July), though on the same day the patient consulted another specialist.  First consultation is 'New', other Specialisation consultation on the same day is 'Review'.  But for head count, this RegNo (305781) should be considered only under New.)

**When I take a report for a date range (from 10-07-2021 to 12-07-2021), the output should be**

| New | Review |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 13 |

But what I am getting for a date range (from 10-07-2021 to 12-07-2021) is (wrong output)

| New | Review |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 10 |

(distinct RegNo in the given date range).

Kindly help me with appropriate query.

[Oracle Table Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xh91N.png)

Comment: Paste your data here as text, dont link to images (See: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)). Then, also show your SQL please.

Comment: Hi, I have pasted the data here.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT
    VisitDate,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN NewReview = 'New' THEN 1 END)    AS New,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN NewReview = 'Review' THEN 1 END) AS Review
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    VisitDate
ORDER BY
    VisitDate;
```